# Matching date with calculated DATEADD date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dateadd

I am trying to create a table with columns containing the current date, prior year date, and additional column for the total sum revenue as below:

cur_date | py_date | py_rev

I'm trying to compare revenue across any daily period across years. Assume all dates and revenue values are included in the same SQL Server table.

I attempted to use a case statement using `[date] = DATEADD(wk,-52,[date])` as the condition to return the appropriate total. The full line code is below:

```
select 
[date] as cur_date,
DATEADD(wk,-52,[date]) py_date,
SUM(case when [date] = DATEADD(wk,-52,[date]) then sum_rev else 0 end) as py_rev
from summary
group by [date]
```

When running this code the py_date is as expected but py_rev returns 0 as if there is no match. What's most confusing is if I hard code a random date in place of the `DATEADD` portion then a total is returned. I have also tried `CAST` to format both date and the `DATEADD` portion as date with no luck.

Is there something about `DATEADD` that will not match to other date columns that I'm missing?

[image: sample data set]

Comment: Please post a small sample of your data.

Comment: Of course `date` cannot be equal to `date` minus 52 weeks. So you end up summing zeros. To get help with what you actually want to do [edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: Also tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: There must be a date/time field in table to apply filter to. Edit question to show actual data.

Comment: Sample data is attached as a link

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*. If you run your query you can see that `cur_date` is never equal to `py_date` in the same row. You need to use lag as per Gordons answer below.

Comment: Sorry but these responses are not helpful and were not helpful to the previous question. I have edited several times with no response which is why I asked in a different manner. The fact of the matter is that assuming [date] is the current date (6/18/2021), DATEADD(wk, -52, [date]) returns a date of 6/19/2020. Assuming that [date] captures every date going back at least 2 years in theory [date] = DATEADD(wk,-52,[date]) should be true when [date] = 6/19/2020, which is in the column. I'm trying to better understand why this method does not work.

Comment: @DaleK I'm not attempting to match the same row. I'm attempting to match the values in each column which works if I hard code the date. (ex. '2020-06-19') If DATEADD returns a value in the same format then why would this not work also?

Comment: @MichaelSummons but you code as written **is** comparing values in the same row, thats how SQL works. The answer you are looking for is Gordons, using lag, to compare the current row to one 52 weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the previous years revenue, then `lag()` is one method.  This works assuming that "previous year" means 52 weeks ago and you have records for all dates:

```
select [date] as cur_date,
       dateadd(week, -52, [date]) as py_date,
       lag(sum_rev, 52 * 7) over (order by date) as py_rev
from summary;
```

If you do not have records for all dates, then another approach is needed.  You can use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select s.date, dateadd(week, -52, s.[date]),
       sprev.sum_rev as py_rev
from summary s left join
     summary sprev
     on sprev.date = dateadd(week, -52, s.[date]);
```